# How do I get all key states when using asm.js/emscripten/SDL?

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl, emscripten, asm.js

When using SDL for keyboard input only certain keys seems to work (arrows, pageup\pagedown).

This is the code I am using:

```
const auto sdlScanCodes = {...SDL_SCANCODE_A, SDL_SCANCODE_F1, SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE, SDL_SCANCODE_LSHIFT ...etc}

SDL_PumpEvents();
const auto sdlKeyStatesPtr = SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr);
for(auto sdlScanCode: sdlScanCodes) {
    const auto sdlKeyCode = SDL_SCANCODE_TO_KEYCODE(sdlScanCode);
    const bool downKeyCode = sdlKeyStatesPtr[sdlKeyCode];
    const bool downScanCode = sdlKeyStatesPtr[sdlScanCode];
}
```

*Update:*
Note that *downScanCode* never works, and as said, *downKeyCode* works for some keys.

Comment: Can you show your event loop instead of just this snippet?  The context is not clear enough to see how you are expecting to see key states change.

Comment: @Jonny D: Updated the answer, thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked when I used the keycodes directly, instead of converting scancodes

```
const auto sdlKeyCodes = {...SDLK_a, SDLK_F1, SDLK_SPACE, SDLK_LSHIFT ...etc}

SDL_PumpEvents();
const auto sdlKeyStatesPtr = SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr);
for(auto sdlKeyCode: sdlKeyCodes ) {
    const bool downKeyCode = sdlKeyStatesPtr[sdlKeyCode];
}
```

Comment: As the linked documentation indicates, you should be using scancodes.  Only some keycode values are the same as their scancode counterparts.  If it's still not working, then something else is the matter.  I know that emscripten works with SDL 1.2, but I'm not sure of the status with SDL 2.  Good luck!

Comment: As a followup to this, the C source port with emscripten and SDL 2.0 was just announced today (12/24/14).  It's now in the official SDL hg repository.

Answer (score 1):

The array returned by `SDL_GetKeyboardState` should be indexed by scancodes in SDL 2.0, not keycodes as in SDL 1.2.  Try doing it without the `SDL_SCANCODE_TO_KEYCODE` conversion.

For reference:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState

Also, I should point out that `SDL_SCANCODE_TO_KEYCODE` is not a general-use conversion macro.  It simply sets an upper bit so that certain scancodes can be unique.  Use `SDL_GetKeyFromScancode` and `SDL_GetScancodeFromKey`.